# JSP: sort HTML table on serverside

Tags: jsp, sorting

I am working on one legacy application.  In JSP there is a html table. I need to write functionality to sort the table based on the column the users clicks.

The table display 20 rows in each page.  Some tables have 3000 rows.  So, there can be about 150 pages.  Upon clicking each page#, servlet is called and gets the next rows.  So each click is a new request.

My question is:  When the page displays, the columns are in ascending order by default.  Next click on the column, should sort it desc order (should sort all 3000 rows) and vice-versa. There are about 10 columns that they can sort data. How can I do this.

Comment: Where is the data for this table stored? Are you retrieving it from the DB on each call, or do you store it in the session? If the latter, how is it structured? A `List<List>` or `Object[][]`? As your question is written, nobody can give you a good answer. Or an answer that has any bearing on your legacy code.

Comment: It is Array of objects. Ex: ManagerData[]. Where "ManagerData" is an object. This Array is stored as request attribute.

Answer (score 0):

An array of objects is easy to sort: you create a custom `Comparator` that will compare different fields depending on a constructor parameter. Then you call `Arrays.sort()`, passing it your array and your custom comparator. This is discussed in the Java tutorial: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html

To identify field to sort, you would simply pass a request parameter. You'd construct the table such that each header has an `onClick` event that sends a new request with the given parameter (I'm sure there's a more modern approach, someone else might answer that).

But none of that will work if you're correct when you say that the array is stored as a *request* attribute. Are you sure it's not stored as a *session* attribute?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  That is helpful.  There are about 7 columns that the users can sort rows as required.  Everytime the column header is clicked, it should alternatively do sorting in ascending/descending order.  How can I capture the column and the order ( ascending / descending ).  Should I just have javascript hidden fields.  But I have about 7 columns that they can sort the rows.  Is there any better approach.

Comment: Hi, any suggestions on this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I gave you a suggestion. If you are unable to take that suggestion and turn it into code, I can't help.